# Netbeans won't open in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, netbeans

I am new to Ubuntu and have recently been working in Netbeans on Ubuntu, however for the last couple of days when opened Netbeans on the desktop nothing happened. It was working fine before. I also tried to open it in the file location but this time it flashed on the launcher as if it were loading up but just disappeared.

Some of the other programs that I used including LibreOffice Calc are not working either.

This happened before with Chrome & Firefox but this was because too many processes were in use I ended these and it worked fine?

I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: I have rebooted a couple of times now and still no change

Comment: Try to start it in a terminal and post any errors you get. If you installed Netbeans using aptget/Software Center execute `netbeans` on a terminal. If you installed using an installer it may be something like `/opt/netbeans-<version>/bin/netbeans`.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of pulling my hair out I finally got it up & running again. I rebooted earlier this morning and there was still no change, I came up with no further possible solution so decided to chance another reboot and voila it worked